# Invoking constructor from within class method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, methods, constructor

In JavaScript, is there a way to "reconstruct" an object inside of a class method by calling the constructor inside the object?  Or do I have to reassign values to each property?

For example, when I learned Java, this was done by simply using the `this` keyword: `this(<constructor arguments>)` or `this()` (for a default constructor).

I've tried the above in JS, and it logs an error: `Type Error on line 129: this is not a function` .

I also tried `this.constructor(<constructor arguments>)`, but it also threw an error:  `Type Error on line 130: Class constructor SecondClock cannot be invoked without 'new'`

So I then tried `new Class(<constructor arguments>)`, and while this doesn't throw an error, it also doesn't reset the existing object.  (Presumably, it simply creates a new object within the method call but dumps it because it's not assigned to anything.)

In my case, the solution isn't too difficult because I'm just learning this stuff and only have 1 property to reset.  But I imagine reassigning every property could get cumbersome if the object had many to work with.

I've tried googling the solution and searching here, but I can't find anywhere that the question's been asked.

Comment: Constructors serve one purpose - to *create* (a.k.a. "construct") a new object. They will not *change* an existing object. In Java `this()` will simply call the constructor and it's used when chaining constructor calls so it's still part of creating a new object. What are you actually trying to do, since it seems like you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So even in Java, one can't "reconstruct" the object, and  this() basically only works in an overloaded constructor before assigning to properties?  

I'm working a simple learning project re asynchronous code. Creating a class that logs seconds from 1 to target with a start() method and that stops and resets the counter with the reset() method.  Currently, in the reset() I am invoking the clearTimeout() and then following it up with this.seconds = 0.  But I was thinking of a situation with a lot of properties and trying to "re-construct" with the constructor.

Comment: You can delegate the initialization of the own properties of an instance to a regular method, just call the method in the constructor, and when you need to re-initialize, call the method instead of the constructor.

Comment: @Teemu is correct. It's common to have something like an `init` method that sets up an object for first use and the constructor to just be something like `constructor() { this.init(); }`. This will allow you to call `init` again to re-set all values to initials.

Comment: Thanks for the comments folks.  This cleared things up for me a lot, in both Java and JavaScript